# Kivy AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following problem: I want to have a screen which shows a list of records taken from my database. This list should allow the user to click on an entry and thus switch to a 'result' screen which shows all the details of that entry.

The `browseButton` in my main screen is supposed to switch to `BrowseWindow` screen and, at the same time, build inside it a list of buttons which correspond to the fetched db entries (this is what the `makeList` function does, by calling WMan().dbFetch()).

All right up to this point. Now, I want to bind an on_release event to these buttons so that clicking them switches the current screen to `ResultWindow` and prints the output there (this is performed by WMan().printRecipe()). However, this triggers the error:

```
     self.ids.result.ids.title.text = recipeName                           
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

I hope I was able to explain my issue clearly enough. Here is my kv file:

```
WMan:
    MainWindow:
    BrowseWindow:
    ResultWindow:
        id: result

<MainWindow>:
    name: 'main'
    browseButton: browseButton

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'browse'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'browse'
                app.root.current_screen.makeList()

        Button:
            id: browseButton
            text: 'result'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = 'result'

<BrowseWindow>:
    name: 'browse'
    on_enter: root.bindList()
    browseList: browseList

    BoxLayout:
        id: browseList
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: .9, None
        pos_hint: {"x": .05, "top": .8}
        #height: self.minimum_height


<ResultWindow>:
    name: 'result'
    on_enter: app.root.printRecipe('test')

    Label:
        id: title
        pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top": .9}
        size_hint: (.9, None)
        height: self.texture_size[0]

    ScrollView:
        id: scroll
        size_hint: (.9, .75)
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.05, "top": .75}
        StackLayout:
            size_hint: .9, None
            orientation: 'lr-tb'
            spacing: 0, 2
            height: self.minimum_height
            Label:
                text: "Ingredients:"
                size_hint: 1, None
                #text_size: self.size
                #halign: 'left'
                height: '30sp'
            BoxLayout:
                id: ingredientsBox
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
```

the py script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class BrowseWindow(Screen):

    def makeList(self):
        recipesList = WMan().dbFetch()
        for i in recipesList:
            self.browseList.add_widget(
                Button(
                    text=i,
                    height='30sp'))
        return self.browseList

    def bindList(self):
        for child in self.browseList.children:
            print(child.text)
            child.bind(on_release = self.listBindings(child)) 

    def listBindings(self, i):
        self.manager.current = 'result'
        WMan().printRecipe(i.text)

class ResultWindow(Screen):
    pass    

class WMan(ScreenManager):

    def dbFetch(self):
        recipesList = ['Recipe1', 'Recipe2', 'Recipe3', 'Recipe4']
        return recipesList   

    def searchRecipe(self, nameInput):
        recipeName = nameInput
        ingsList = ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolor']
        steps = "Sed at tortor condimentum, congue nibh sit amet, ornare ligula. "
        return recipeName, ingsList, steps

    def printRecipe(self, nameInput):
        recipeName, ingsList, steps = self.searchRecipe(nameInput)

        self.ids.result.ids.title.text = recipeName                           

        for i in range(0, len(ingsList)):
            self.current_screen.ids.ingredientsBox.add_widget(
                Label(
                    text=ingsList[i]))


kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that everywhere that you use `WMan()` you are creating a new instance of `WMan` that has no relation to what is in your GUI. And since the `ids` are assigned when `WMan` gets displayed, there are no `ids` in your `WMan` instances that are not displayed.

You can fix this by replacing `WMan()` with `App.get_running_app().root` everywhere. That gives you a reference to the root `Widget` of the `App`, which is `WMan` in your case.

Comment: this triggers the following error:
 ``` File "D:\Python\Practice\test.kv", line 26, in <module>
     on_enter: root.bindList()
   File "D:\Python\Practice\trial.py", line 27, in bindList
     child.bind(on_release = self.listBindings(child)) 
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 419, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
 AssertionError: None is not callable```

Comment: I'll answer my own question: I solved this second error by creating a ListButton(Button) class and moving the method listBindings() inside it. Then, I bind ListButton using a lambda function so that: self.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.listBindings(self))

Comment: That error is not triggered by my answer. Your code `child.bind(on_release = self.listBindings(child))` is running the `listBindings()` method and trying to bind the return of that method to the `on_release`, but that method returns `None`. I suspect you really want to bind that method (not its return), so use `child.bind(on_release = self.listBindings)`.

Comment: I did not mean to say that your answer directly triggered this error, but I would not get to this error without first applying your fix. Anyway, I actually need to pass the button itself as an argument, since `listBindings()` needs to grab the text of the button to then perform `App.get_running_app().root.printRecipe(i.text)`

Comment: The `on_release` adds the `Button` instance as an argument.